# change jenkins workspace and attach file with email using jenkins email-ext plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to jenkins and i want to add my test report with the email attachment.

I am using

```
Email-ext
```

plugin to send email. Email is sent successfully but the attached file is not sent.

My test report generates in eclipse porject workspace inside and path is

```
E:\eclipse_environment\workspace\smautomation_jenkin\assets\chromeTestReport\
```

how i can attache my test file with email using this plug-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using mac and my solution works for mac.But i think the concept will be same for all os.

Actually, jenkin attach file from its workspace automatically. For this no expression is not required. For example, in my mac, jenkins workspace is

```
/users/dev/.jenkins/workspace
```

and i keep a file here named

```
 report.txt.
```

And in "attachment" of email-ext plugin, just write

```
report.txt
```

no need to write any other thing. jenkins will go to its workspace and check "report.txt" exist or not. if exist, it send it as attachement.

Now question about the jenkins workspace.

Actually jenkins has its own workspace. You may need another workspace. To check jenkins workspace, go like this:

```
jenkins > manage jenkins > configure system.
```

Now at top u will see

```
Home directory
```

and theres an

```
Advanced
```

option. Click on it and u will see

```
Workspace Root Directory: and its value is   
${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace
```

ITEM_ROOTDIR is where .jenkins exist.    For me this is

```
/users/dev/.jenkins
```

Actually u can see this at the first line:

```
    Home directory  -- ur ITEM_ROOTDIR is shown in this line.
```

now go to  ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/ and u will see a folder name workspace.

Now if u keep any file in this workspace, jenkin will send this file as attachement. Obviously u have to mention it in email-ext plugin "attachment" section.

Now if u want to change ur workspace, change ur

```
Workspace Root Directory:
```

like this 
    ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/jobs/test/workspace

it depends on you.Change according to ur wish.

the most important thing is, if u change ur workspce from

```
jenkins > manage jenkins > configure system > Advanced option under Home directory

this will be ur default workspace.
```

If u want to make a specific workspace for only

```
one project
```

than u have to follow another procedure.

Just create a maven job (project). Than enter into the project,

```
//click on configure, now click on "Advanced" option under "Build"
//For free style project, this is in "Advanced project option"
```

There, u will see

```
Use custom workspace
```

check this option, and give ur needed workspace. For me i give like this:

```
 /users/dev/workspace/test1/
```

and this is

```
the workspace only for this project.
```

Now u can send file from here as an attachement.

```
one most important thing is u must restart jenkins server
```

to set the new workspace to ur job.

Actually u can copy files into jenkins workspace from another directory using cp command in

```
Execute shell option.
```

Now just give the file name in attachement of email-ext plugin and jenkins will send this file as attachment with ur email.

cheers.........

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me, to include html file in jenkins workspace to a mail body.

***jenkins -> configuration -> Editable Email Notification***

***Content Type :*** HTML(text/html)

***Default Content:*** ${FILE,path="build/reports/tests/test/index.html"}

**Don't start file path with "/"**