# Jenkins send mail based on build parameters with attachments

Tags: email, jenkins

I want to send mail with attachment to recipients in post build task if value of Env parameter is "FAILEDBUILD". This value I am providing at the start of the build in "build with parameter" window.

Answer (score 0):

One thing what you can do is, in Build Section of the Jenkins Job, you can configure something like below.

[image]

Then in Post Build Action, using the below plugin will help you in doing that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vinay. However my requirement is bit different. Below are points to consider. 1> Email is already going for success and failed pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Vinay. However my requirement is bit different. Below are points to consider. 1> Email is already going for success and failed pipeline.  2> I am running a separate script if for example stage value is FAILEDSTAGE which will be generating a log file. I want to send this log as an attachment to the list of users.   3> So, basically I dont want to stop the pipeline. I just want to send the logs as an attachment to the user lists.   4> Cant send mail from system due to restriction that's why looking on to jenkins to perform this.

Comment: In that case I think you should refer to this answer. https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067682/change-jenkins-workspace-and-attach-file-with-email-using-jenkins-email-ext-plug&hl=en-IN

Answer (score 0):

Try with the text finder plugin , you can set the build status depending on a single keyword or regular expresion looking on the console output.